# Android: Inform main activity about CheckBox of custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-actionmode

I have a Custom `BaseAdapter` showing a `ListView` containing a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. The `TextView` has an `OnClickListener` implemented to perform a specific action when clicked on the text. Within the Adapter I have a `OnCheckedChangeListener` registered which keeps track of which item is checked (because of the `ListView` recycling).

I want to start an `ActionMode` when I check a `CheckBox` and stop it when I uncheck it.

How can I inform the main activity hosting the adapter that a check has been made?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/codeguru42/CheckableLinearLayout) is a Android Studio project that shows an example of how to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a listener call back interface, something like:

```
public interface ListenerCheckBox
{
    public void onRowChecked(int rowNun);
}
```

Then, make your main activity implement this listener:

```
public class ActivityMain implements ListenerCheckBox
```

Then, when you instantiate your custom BaseAdapter, pass in the listener:

```
//kv 3rd parameter would be listener
CustomBaseAdapter customBaseAdapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, items, this);
```

Then, in the constructor of your CustomBaseAdapter, set a member field to the listener:

```
public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items, ListenerCheckBox listenerCheckBox)
{
    mListenerCheckBox = listenerCheckBox;
    ...
}
```

Then, every time an item is checked, call:

```
mListenerCheckBox.onRowChecked(rowNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/codeguru42/CheckableLinearLayout) is a Android Studio project that shows an example of how to do what you are asking. In particular, check out [the check listener](https://github.com/codeguru42/CheckableLinearLayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/codeguru/checkablelinearlayout/example/CheckableListener.java) and its `onClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mMode != null) {
        mMode = mListView.startActionMode(new ExampleMultiChoiceModeListener(mActivity));
    }

    mListView.setItemChecked(mPosition, ((Checkable) v).isChecked());
}
```